# Habilitar FilePicker para selecionar múltiplos arquivos

Tags: android, webview

Bom dia,
sou iniciante na programação de apps Android e estou com uma incógnita sobre como habilitar o filepicker para selecionar múltiplos arquivos. Meu código funciona, porém só seleciona um arquivo por vez.

Segue o código:

**BaseActivity.java**

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (reqCode == WebEngine.KEY_FILE_PICKER) {
                String picturePath = FilePicker.getPickedFilePath(this, data);
                if (webEngine != null) {
                    webEngine.uploadFile(data, picturePath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**FilePicker.java**

```
package com.teste.final.utility;
FilePicker.java
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Ashiq on 6/1/16.
 */

public class FilePicker {

    private static String pictureTempPath = "";
    private static final String CHOOSER_MSG = "Escolha uma opção";
    private static final String IMAGE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
    private static final String IMAGE_EXTENSION = ".jpg";

    /**
     * Start picker intent
     *
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static Intent getPickFileIntent(Context context) {
        Intent chooserIntent = null;

        List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        addIntentsToList(context, intentList, getGalleryIntent());
        addIntentsToList(context, intentList, getCameraIntent(context));
        addIntentsToList(context, intentList, getFileIntent());

        if (intentList.size() > 0) {
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1), CHOOSER_MSG);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        }

        return chooserIntent;
    }

    /**
     * Start camera picker intent
     *
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static Intent getCameraPickerIntent(Context context) {
        Intent chooserIntent = null;

        List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        addIntentsToList(context, intentList, getCameraIntent(context));

        if (intentList.size() > 0) {
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1), CHOOSER_MSG);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        }

        return chooserIntent;
    }

    /**
     * Start gallery picker intent
     *
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static Intent getGalleryPickerIntent(Context context) {
        Intent chooserIntent = null;

        List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        addIntentsToList(context, intentList, getGalleryIntent());

        if (intentList.size() > 0) {
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1), CHOOSER_MSG);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        }

        return chooserIntent;
    }

    /**
     * Get captured image path
     *
     * @param context
     * @param data
     * @return
     */
    public static String getPickedFilePath(Context context, Intent data) {
        String filePath = null;

        boolean isCameraIntent = (data == null || data.getData() == null);

        if (isCameraIntent) {
            filePath = pictureTempPath;
        } else {
            filePath = getImagePath(context, data.getData());
            /*if (filePath == null) {
                filePath = data.getData().getPath();
            }*/
        }

        return filePath;
    }

    private static String getImagePath(Context context, Uri imageUri) {
        String path = null;
        try {
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            // Get DB Cursor to get Image link
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                // Get image path
                path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return path;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a gallery intent
     *
     * @return
     */
    private static Intent getGalleryIntent() {
        // Define gallery intent
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    }

    private static Intent getFileIntent() {
        // Define file intent
        Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chooseFile.setType("*/*");
        return chooseFile;
    }


    /**
     * Creates a camera intent
     *
     * @return
     */
    private static Intent getCameraIntent(Context ctx) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(ctx.getPackageManager()) != null) {

            cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtils.DateTimeFormat.YYMMDD_HHMMSS.toString(), Locale.US).format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = IMAGE_PREFIX + timeStamp;
            File photoFile = new File(path, imageFileName + IMAGE_EXTENSION);

            pictureTempPath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();

            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        }

        return cameraIntent;
    }

    /**
     * Make a list of choices to display to user
     *
     * @param context
     * @param list
     * @param intent
     * @return
     */
    private static void addIntentsToList(Context context, List<Intent> list, Intent intent) {

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            Intent targetedIntent = new Intent(intent);
            targetedIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            list.add(targetedIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A sua pergunta não está clara. Você quer seleccionar vários arquivos ao mesmo tempo ou quer abrir um *chooser* (janela) que permita escolher uma aplicação, entre várias, para seleccionar um arquivo?

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui: https://temandei.com, se você acessar este site pelo navegador do celular você vai notar que o navegador lhe permite selecionar vários arquivos de uma só vez. Eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso na webview. Eu só consegui selecionar 1 arquivo por vez. Eu tenho este código com o FilePicker selecionando 1 arquivo por vez, eu escolho o app e mando abrir o arquivo. Mas não é o que eu quero, quero simplesmente selecionar vários arquivos de uma só vez como no exemplo que dei acima.